# Why is my javascript onchange function not getting called?

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically generated html which has multiple input elements , that have an onchange function like this : `onchange=adStGroup();`. In my html I have created a javascript function like so :

```
function adStGroup(jsObj){
    console.log(jsObj.name);
}
```

If I go to developer tools change the function to : `onchange=adStGroup(this);` and make some changes in the input element , the name of the element is logged .
But since the dynamically html does not contain the this argument , hence , on `window onload` , I am removing the default onchange and adding another onchange , like so :

```
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementById("f5erz").getElementsByTagName('input').length;i++){
        document.getElementById("f5erz").getElementsByTagName('input')[i].removeAttribute('onchange');
        document.getElementById("f5erz").getElementsByTagName('input')[i].setAttribute('onchange','javascript:adStGroup(this);');
}
```

Now the dynamically generated html input elements contain the `this` argument, but If I make any change to the input element , the corresponding method is not getting called . **Why So ?**

**How can I still pass the this reference to such dynamically generated input elements ?**

**Note :** I am using IE document mode emulated as 5 , since the app works only in this version .

Comment: I don't believe you should be using `remove/set Attribute`, more like `addEventListener`

Comment: @Lixus . Don't think `addEventListener` will work in IE mode 5 . And in `attachEvent`, I do not know how to pass the `this` parameter. I actually tried both, but none seemed to work.